# PHP errors in Nginx error log instead of Monolog log files

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, monolog

I'm getting a following error in my application:

```
2018/08/31 06:13:24 [error] 20208#20208: *139993 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function setTime() on boolean in /var/www/website.com/releases/20180829221434Z/src/Somenamespace/SomeClass.php:218
```

Of course, I understand that this is a problem in my code and I have to fix it, but what bothers me is that this exception is not caught and logged by Monolog, but instead it ends up in Nginx log.

My questions are:
1. Is is even possible that Monolog catches and logs this kind of error?
2. If the first one is positive, is there any particular configuration in PHP (7.0.18) of Symfony (3.4) that should be applied for my application?

Comment: Is the exception thrown during execution of your scripts, or during startup of the Symfony kernel? In the former, it should log for as far as I know.

Comment: It happens during normal application usage, when customers play with the app.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this? I have similar issue